# Handle content which contains laravel blade code in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

#Asking

Help me for my problem,

I have blog content and it has syntax examples like `{{ $title }}` because my content describes laravel blade.

**Problem**
When I render my blog content on Vuejs everything goes wrong because there is a sytax blade `{{ $title }}`

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you show some code? Seems like you are mixing blade and vue.

Answer (score 0):

please use below code
`{{ $title }}` - use for laravel blade
`{{{$title}}}` - use for Vue js in laravel blade page

if you want to bind  both please try with below code

In script tag
`var title = '{{$title}}';`
In Vue js CLI
`data:return{ title:'{{$title}}' }`

If you still getting a problem, then please brief all about your problem with the code I will resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I try to parse README.md file from [hexters/rolevel](https://github.com/hexters/rolevel) and I render the README.md content with vuejs, and  my apps error and Blank